# dapp without test.js

Tags: solidity, dapps, ethereumjs, testing

We can test our smart contract in remix and can perform several workflow checks before putting the contract in the final sol file in the dapp project. This way we can ensure that everything is in place and executing as expected. Then why do we need a test.js file separately to put a check on the contract?

Comment: How other people would know if you have tested your contract at all if you do not publish tests?

Comment: okay, i got it. But if i am building a self project then can i avoid creating a seperate test.js file?

Comment: If there are no other users for your project then it really does not matter.